# In JAVA, what is the fastest way to convert RGB value of image to binary?

Tags: java, image, binary, type-conversion, rgb

I am trying to get the RGB value of any given pixel on an image into 12 bit binary, with each channel represented by 4 bits. For example, if a pixel has it's red channel at '255', or in binary "11111111". I wish to convert that to "1111".

I have got a code working, but it is rather slow, and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Here's what i did.

1. I use the method getRGB(x, y) to get the RGB value of one pixel.
   e.g. -4278864
2. I convert that into 3 separate channels e.g. r 190 g 181 b 176
3. I divide that by 16 to get integer equivalent of 4 bit
   representation
4. I convert the number to a binary.
5. Add 0's in front of the binary if the binary generated is less
   than 4 bit.
6. Concatenate to a 12bit binary to represent 12bit color output. e.g. 101110111011

Here are my code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class LoadImageApp extends Component {
    private static int[] rgbArray;
    private static double bitPerColor = 4.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       BufferedImage img = null;
       String fileName = "Image.jpg";

       try {
           //Read in new image file
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/"+fileName));
       } 
       catch (IOException e){
       }

       if (img == null) {
             System.out.println("No image loaded");
        } 
       else {

                //Get RGB Value
                int val = img.getRGB(500, 500);
                System.out.println("rgbValue from getRGB is: " + val);


                //Convert to three separate channels
                int a = (0xff000000 & val) >>> 24;
                int r = (0x00ff0000 & val) >> 16;
                int g = (0x0000ff00 & val) >> 8;
                int b = (0x000000ff & val);

                System.out.println("rgbValue in RGB is: ");
                System.out.println("a " + a + " r " + r + " g " + g + " b " + b);

                double power = Math.pow(2.0, bitPerColor);
                //Convert each channel to binary
                String r4bit = Integer.toBinaryString((int)(r/(power)));
                String g4bit = Integer.toBinaryString((int)(g/(power)));
                String b4bit = Integer.toBinaryString((int)(b/(power)));



                //Convert concatonate 0's in front to get desired bit count
                int rDifference = (int)bitPerColor - r4bit.length();
                int gDifference = (int)bitPerColor - g4bit.length();
                int bDifference = (int)bitPerColor - b4bit.length();


                for (int i = rDifference; i > 0; i--){
                    r4bit="0"+r4bit;}

                for (int i = gDifference; i > 0; i--){
                    g4bit = "0"+g4bit;}

                for (int i = bDifference; i > 0; i--){
                    b4bit = "0"+b4bit;}

                //Concatonate three channel together to form one binary
                String rgbValue = r4bit + g4bit + b4bit;

                System.out.println("rgbValue in binary is: " + rgbValue);


           }     
       }
}
```

It all works fine as as desired. However it's just really, really ugly, and slow, 2-3 seconds just to read one pixel. I was hoping to use the code to read a section of an image at a time, but i can imaging it taking AGES.

So any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main thing is, avoid `String` if you don't need it. Just use `int` and bit-wise operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original code (in hex) is `0x00rrggbb`.  You want to convert this to `0x00000rgb`. This will do it:

```
int rgb24 = ....;
int rgb12 = (rgb24 & 0x00f00000) >> 12 + 
            (rgb24 & 0x0000f000) >> 8  + 
            (rgb24 & 0x000000f0) >> 4;
```

If you wanted to "round" to the nearest color instead of truncating you could do this:

```
int r = (rgb24 & 0x00ff0000);
int g = (rgb24 & 0x0000ff00);
int b = (rgb24 & 0x000000ff);
r += (r >= 0x00f00000) ? 0x00080000 : 0;
g += (g >= 0x0000f000) ? 0x00000800 : 0;
b += (b >= 0x000000f0) ? 0x00000008 : 0;
int rgb12 = (r & 0x00f00000) >> 12 + (g & 0x0000f000) >> 8 + (b & 0x000000f0) >> 4;
```

This rounds up but only if the high-order 4 bits are not already 1111 (when you would risk overflow).

Comment: Would this still be an accurate representation of each color? For example, if you're basically converting 256 'reds' down to 16 'reds', will the bit-shift still keep the colors accurate? Isn't the bit-shift going to just cut-off 4 of the bits?

Comment: If you convert an 8-bit value to a 4-bit value you are unavoidably discarding low-order bits of information.  Just as rounding prices to the nearest dollar loses detail but not overall magnitude.  As to whether the color shifts, that is also unavoidable since there are now only 16 possible levels for each channel instead of 256.

Comment: Yeah thats cool, I was only asking, for my benefit more than anything. I know that you're going to loose some level of color, but was just wondering whether 'strong reds' would still be strong, 'weak reds' still be weak, etc, or whether you're just chopping a few bits off the end.

Comment: I updated my answer for a more "rounded" result.  In general yes, strong reds would remain strong, although it would depend to some extent on the color space and the output device.

Comment: That's a really elegant solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that might be slowing it down, such as...

1. Getting each pixel individually from the `BufferedImage`
2. Using `Math.pow()` and possibly `Integer.toBinaryString()`, multiple times in the loop
3. Using `String`s all the way through, rather than numbers like `int` or `short`. If you want a `String`, maybe do a single conversion from `short` --> `String` at the end.

I would probably try to do something like this...

```
// Get all the pixels
int pixelCount = imageWidth*imageHeight;
int[] pixelArray = new int[pixelCount];
img.getRGB(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight,pixelArray,0,1);

// For storing the 4-bit data
short[] convertedArray = new short[pixelCount];

// calculate the conversion factor a single time
double power = Math.pow(2.0, bitPerColor);

// Loop over the pixels
for (int p=0;p<pixelCount;p++){
    int pixel = pixelArray[p];

    // Convert into separate channels
    int a = (0xff000000 & val) >>> 24;
    int r = (0x00ff0000 & val) >> 16;
    int g = (0x0000ff00 & val) >> 8;
    int b = (0x000000ff & val);

    // Convert to 4-bit
    a /= power;
    r /= power;
    g /= power;
    b /= power;

    // Create the short for the pixel (4 channels * 4 bits = a 2-byte short)
    short newPixel = (a & 0x0000000f) << 24 | (r & 0x0000000f) << 16 | (g & 0x0000000f) << 8 | (b & 0x0000000f);
    convertedArray[p] = newPixel;

    // If you want to have the value as a String, do it here.
    String binary = Short.toBinaryString(newPixel);
}
```

Comment: Mostly good comments on optimization -- but you're still running 'division' operators (and double division, at that) inside the loop, when you should be doing bitshifts.  Try a = a >> 4.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, I noticed you used the String plus operator for appending. I know it's simple code but that takes some work when it is in a loop. The operator calls a constructor to execute its function.
How big is the loop anyway?

Instead of using the plus operator, perhaps use other classes like StringBuilder or a Java equivalent of it. Tell me which class you end up using.
Investigate by timing your code!

When you want to see your possible bottlenecks, look at LOOPS in a heap or stack first since there are potentially many code executions. This should be a coding rule somewhere...

Try it out & have fun. Pls vote for my answer. I need a badge and more points :-)

Tommy Kwee

Comment: Please don't ask people to vote for your answer just because you want more points and badges - if you write good/correct answers, the points will be awarded to you.

Comment: @synia and others,  Allow me to be clear. If you use StringBuilder, use the append method.

Answer (score -2):

The value I have collected in the RGB when set using SetRGB will it provide me an image of binary for where the area where the image is present is white and the area whre the image is absent is black ?